# sass doesn't like inline variable operation and multiply by 0

Tags: sass

I was hoping I could do something like this but that doesn't work for two reasons

- first it doesn't like the $i - 1 that gives me 'invalid variable'
- then it doesn't like multiplying 0 by 10

I got it working by declaring another variable to do my -1 then an if statement to perform this if that doesn't = 0 but it got ugly really quickly!

> ```
> @for $i from 1 through 10
>    .num-#{$i}
>      margin: 0 #{($i-1)*10}px
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this works for me:

```
@for $i from 1 through 10
   .num-#{$i}
      margin: 0 #{($i * 10 - 10)}px
```

I multiplied first and substracted later. But, did you try adding spaces? Like:

```
$i - 1
```

instead of
    $i-1

Because i'm thinking sass is interpretating it like a single variable instead of an operation.

Comment: ah thanks! that does seem to work. What about the 0 multiplication, I don't see why it's a problem, 0 * a number is 0 why is it an error.

Comment: It isn't, I think it's confusing "$i-1" for a variable, instead of doing the $i "minus" 1 operation. I tried it myself, and the error sass gave was that $i-1 was an undefined variable. But what gives. I'm glad I was able to help.